# How can I tell if my Git LFS migration worked?

Tags: git, git-lfs, git-lfs-migrate

To migrate my Git repo to Git LFS, I did this command:

```
> git lfs migrate import --everything --include="*.dll"
migrate: Sorting commits: ..., done.
migrate: Rewriting commits: 100% (9376/9376), done.
{long list of branch names and hashes}
migrate: Updating refs: ..., done.
migrate: checkout: ..., done.
```

Then again with the "info" option:

```
> git lfs migrate info --everything --include="*.dll"
migrate: Sorting commits: ..., done.
migrate: Examining commits: 100% (13199/13199), done.
*.dll   451 MB  380/380 files(s)        100%
```

Does this mean that 451 MB of dll files in the history were converted to LFS storage? Or that they weren't?
If I get the info without the --include option, it says this:

```
> git lfs migrate info --everything
migrate: Sorting commits: ..., done.
migrate: Examining commits: 100% (13199/13199), done.
*.a     652 MB      55/55 files(s)      100%
*.dll   451 MB    380/380 files(s)      100%
*.cpp   214 MB  2605/2605 files(s)      100%
*.docx  109 MB      49/49 files(s)      100%
```

Why are the .cpp files (and others) included in the list along with the .dll files? I never intentionally converted or migrated .cpp files to Git LFS.